# Bash auto_completion with Xubuntu and xrdp from windows

Tags: bash, xubuntu, auto-completion

I'm using Xubuntu and connecting over RemoteDesktop with Windows 7.

Everything works fine, but the auto_completion in my bash doesn't work.
I checked the .bashrc file in my home directory and also the /etc/bash.bashrc.

I uncommend the lines below in my local bashrc configuration and also in bash.bashrc, but nothing changes.

```
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

Comment: I am very curious as to why this only shows up on remote sessions but not on sessions directly logged in on the console. It happens with either VNC or XRDP - which is not surprising as behind the covers XRDP just invokes VNC to do the rendering. It is I presume because the X server built into VNC is different from the Xorg one but it is still puzzling why this occurs - after all the change suggested here should only affect the "Super-Tab" key combo not the simple "Tab" key. Does this imply that somehow VNC is always showing the "Super" key depressed when tab is hit? And as a final point, I hav

Comment: This issue is still present in Xubuntu 14.04 when using VNC. And implementig the change fix the issue. Remember to search the second occurence of "Super&gt; Tab" like explained in the steeldriver answer; it's in the "custom" section.

Comment: @user294420 I couldnt quite understand the change to be employed can I have a little more explanation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [xrdp tab does not work](http://askubuntu.com/questions/584432/xrdp-tab-does-not-work)

Comment: This is still broken in xubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You may find that this is a more general issue with interception of the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key under remote XFCE4 sessions, rather than a problem with bash completion itself.

I had a similar issue running XFCE4 over VNC and the workaround for me was to edit the `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml` file to unset the following mapping

```
<       <property name="&lt;Super&gt;Tab" type="string" value="switch_window_key"/>
---
>       <property name="&lt;Super&gt;Tab" type="string" value="empty"/>
```

**Note that there may be two entries, and the first already has the value "empty". If this is the case, edit the second entry.**
I found this solution online somewhere and can't really take credit for it.

Comment: Good shot, but i found this issue also with google. This property has already this value at my xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml by default. The link: http://codebangers.com/?p=134

Comment: Damn. I wounder why this value is by default "empty". Checked this with less and find a second entry. But this time with the value "switch_window_key". Changed > restart > works!!!! Thank you :)

Comment: @steeldriver I couldnt quite understand the change to be employed can I have a little more explanation?

Comment: Edit that file and replace `switch_window_key` with `empty` on that line. I used nano to edit the file. I then restarted VNC with `sudo service vncserver restart`. It just worked for me.

Comment: I was *sure* this was an RDP issue.  I was wrong.  Thanks for this.

Comment: this did not fix the issue for me when using XRDP and XFCE4. I had one entry up top set to `switch_window_key` and another down below set to `empty`. I set the first entry for `Super&gt;Tab` to `empty` and did `sudo xrdp restart` and re-logged in to no change.