# xrdp desktop environment comparison

Tags: gnome, kde, xfce, xrdp

I know that this question might tend to somehow opinion based answers but I think it is very helpful anyways.

I am using `xrdp` to my Ubuntu Computer (from Windows and Linux). I have figured out that every Desktop Environment has some "bugs". E.g. with xfce, [TAB is not working properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/352121/bash-auto-completion-with-xubuntu-and-xrdp-from-windows), or Gnome has [some Problems too](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/1251281).

My question now is if someone has a comparison **based on actual facts** between Gnome, xfce and KDE (and also others) with using **xrdp**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you can't and this is unfair to make a comparison or whatever decision using xrdp.

Indeed xrdp is just an open source implementation of the Microsoft RDP protocol, and frankly it's still not mature enough to be stable.

Moreover, every Desktop Environment has its own problem with xrdp, even unity.
Problems range from keyboard layout differences , no window decoration, no language switching, no top panel in Unity and many other problems.

So in couple of words, to have a fair and logical comparison you should work on a physical system running those environments.

Personally, I have more than 4 years of experience using xrdp and other protocols and for bad till now, it doesn't get stable in some way.

PS: I advise you to take a look at [X11RDP](http://scarygliders.net/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that I can only get the full "experience" using a physical System. But as I have a rack Server this is not an Option. There are many comparisons out the for physical Systems - I don't Need to ask for this. But there are no comparisons using xrdp. That's why I'm asking.